# Are bugs nullified in a dish if they were placed unchecked by accident?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, bugs

If someone cooked a dish with vegetables that require checking for bugs, but did not do so, and cooked in a conventional over or a pot, is this food forbidden after the fact? Does this also apply if it was intentional (or should I say, the person did not know about the Halacha but would not care if they would).

Comment: What sort of dish are we talking about?

Comment: Let's say a Quiche. Also I just reviewed my question and would like to further ask if anything cooked in that oven after is forbidden.

Comment: See https://dinonline.org/2015/04/12/parashas-shemini-halachos-of-bugs-in-food/ and https://oukosher.org/halacha-yomis/i-found-a-dead-fly-in-my-hot-pot-of-soup-what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-it/

Comment: okat so I just figured out that it says in Badei Hashulchan 100:46 citing Shach 84:35: "Vegetables that the chance of finding a bug in a serving is 50% needs to be checked and the obligation to check is biblical. If it was cooked without being checked after the fact the food is permitted since it could be that there weren't bugs and it could be that the bugs were crushed.[5]"

Comment: Now the only question is if an irreligious person did not know these Halacha's, but even if they would know they would not care, does this permission still apply.

Comment: Please [edit] your question if you want to ask more, also please remember this site is for not for personal questions, these require a dialogue with a trained rabbi to get to a proper answer (e.g., which dish, which cooking method, which vegetable in which location, etc.) All of these have halachic implications

Answer (score -1):

So I have found the answer, yes it would be permitted, as I infered from the Lashon of the answer quoting the sources I have noted, that this would apply to even intentional, because in Halacha (I think) when it says "after the fact", this applies also to intentional actions. Please also take note that this answer was addressing vegetables that have a 50+ % chance of infestation, and I don't belive that mushrooms are in this catagory (they are probably in the "miut hamatzui" catagory, which if one cooked with is Kosher BeDieved (Shulchan Aruch, Yoreh De’ah 84:9).